# Angle between points in hyperbolic space

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm following the work from the paper, [Poincaré Embeddings for
Learning Hierarchical Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08039)  which uses the Poincaré ball model of hyperbolic space. In equation [1] they give the distance between any two points as

$$
d(\textbf{u},\textbf{v}) = \text{arcosh} \left ( 1 + 2\frac{||\textbf{u}-\textbf{v}||^2}{(1-||\textbf{u}||^2)(1-||\textbf{v}||^2)} \right )
$$

here $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm and the vectors are constrained to an open unit ball in $d$ dimensions, $\textbf{u}, \textbf{v} \in  \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathcal{R}^d ; ||\textbf{x}||^2 < 1  \}$. So far, so good.

I'd like to consider the notion of an "angle" between two points $\textbf{a}, \textbf{b}$ in this space. By fixing the center $\textbf{c}$ as a special point, one could use the standard angle in Euclidean space defined by the line segments $\textbf{a} \rightarrow \textbf{c} \rightarrow \textbf{b}$, but this doesn't seem natural since the entire nature of the metric is different. Is there some notion of an angle that makes more sense?

Comment: Since you have the three hyperbolic distances among the three points, can’t you use the hyperbolic Law of Cosines?

Comment: The Poincare sphere model is conformal. So any angle in it looks like as if it were an Euclidean angle. However, the center of the hyperbolic space is meaningless. This way you cannot define an angle between points but not because of the difference in the metric but because of the lack of a natural center. (If you shift $a$ and $b$ in such a way that the distance between them remains the same  then the  angle will change. So your angle depends not only on the two points but also on the special choice of the "center".)

Comment: I agree totally, @zoli. It’s not clear what the *meaning* of such an angle would be. But perhaps OP finds himself standing at that “center” point, lost in hyperbolic space, and needs the angle for navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the hyperbolic Law of Cosines. It reads this way:
$$
\cosh(\overline{\mathbf a\mathbf b})=
\cosh(\overline{\mathbf a\mathbf c})
\cosh(\overline{\mathbf c\mathbf b})-
\sinh(\overline{\mathbf a\mathbf c})
\sinh(\overline{\mathbf c\mathbf b})\cos(\angle\mathbf a\mathbf c\mathbf b)\,,
$$
and of course you want to solve for the cosine of the angle at the vertex of the triangle.

Comment: I guess when you know [where to look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines) you'll find a lot more information. Thanks!